# Does $X \bot Y$ and $X \bot Z$ imply that ($p(x,y,z)=p(x)p(y,z)$)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose for three random variables $X$ , $Y$ and $Z$:

$X \bot Y$ and $X \bot Z$

It is intuitive to say $X$ and $(Y, Z)$ are independent. In other words:

$p(x, y, z)=p(x)p(y, z)$

Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Suppose that $X,Y$ are independent and take on the values $1,-1$ with probability 1/2, respectively. Let $Z = XY$. Then, $X \perp Y$ and $X \perp Z$, however $X$ is not independent of $(Y,Z)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it also wrong for binary random variables?